# Unloading Datagrid Row?

Tags: wpf, performance, binding, datagrid, loading

I have an issue when I set the `.ItemsSource()` on a `DataGrid` for the second time. It's much slower than the first time (when the Datagrid didn't have any previous `ItemsSource`).

I see also that `UnloadingRow` is fired many times, and that may be related. Is there a way to force the Datagrid to just discard the current `.ItemsSource`, and accept a new one without unloading rows or data?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code while closing datagrid.

```
private void close(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid1.Items.Clear();
    }
```